# Why are there two "be" in one clause?

Tags: grammar

> Government claims that there **is** no poverty **are** belied by the number of homeless people on the streets.

Why are there two "be" in one clause?

Comment: I think maybe what is confusing you is that *claims* here is a noun, not a verb.

Comment: The subject is the noun phrase "government claims that there is no poverty", where "claims" is head and "that there is no poverty" is a content  clause functioning as complement of "claims". So we have one "be" in the subordinate clause in the subject, and a second "be" as the verb of the main clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be parsing this incorrectly.  There are (at least) two clauses here.

The main clause is

> [ ... ] are belied by the number of homeless people ...

Where the part in brackets [ ... ] is the subject.

The head word in the subject is "claims"  (and it is plural, so the verb "are" is correct).  This word is modified by the word "Government" (an attributive noun) and a relative clause.

The relative clause is "that there is no poverty".  It has its own verb, but this clause is subordinate.  It is part of the subject of the sentence, not the main verb of the sentence.

Such sentences are very common. Complex sentences have more than one clause and more than one verb.

Comment: +1 But that’s just a normal content clause functioning as complement of  the noun *claim* (notice you can’t change *that* for *which* and also that the clause has no gap in it.) It’s not a relative clause.

Answer (score 1):

> Government claims that there is no poverty are belied by the number of homeless people on the streets.

This example is fine; *Government* is an attributive noun describing *claims*, the subject.

In its simplest form, the sentence is

> Claims are belied.

Answer (score 1):

Excellently explained by the other two answers, yet I offer my own explanation in addition to theirs.

Perhaps slightly modifying the sentence will help you see better.

> **Those** government claims **which say** that there is no poverty, are belied by the number of homeless people on the streets.

Quoting @stangdon from his comment on the question, "claims" here is acting as a noun and not a verb. It might be interesting to know that there's an entire category of sentences like these called "Garden Path Sentences". At first glance, they seem grammatically incorrect, but they do not violate any rules and are perfectly acceptable. To pique your interest, I will quote one here.

> Fat people eat accumulates.

In this sentence, at first you may assume "eat" is the verb. But the verb in this sentence is actually "accumulates".

Rewording the sentence a little helps.

> The fat that people eat accumulates.

The intended meaning is that what accumulates is the fat that people eat. You can Google Garden Path Sentences to get some more practice at comprehension!